# AttachedToParent Task confusion

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, console-application

I have a problem understanding how `AttachedToParent` parameter works.

Here is the sample code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<int[]> parentTask = Task.Run(()=> 
        {
            int[] results = new int[3];

            Task t1 = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); results[0] = 0; }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            Task t2 = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); results[1] = 1; }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            Task t3 = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); results[2] = 2; }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            t3.Start();

            return results;
        });

        Task finalTask = parentTask.ContinueWith(parent =>
        {
            foreach (int result in parent.Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        });

        finalTask.Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

As I understand, when a Task has child Tasks, the parent Task finishes when all the child tasks are ready. The problem with this example is that the output looks like this:

```
0
0
0
```

This means that the parent Task was not waiting for its child tasks to finish. The only way to get a valid result `0 1 2` is to use Wait on all of the child Taks, by adding some piece of code like this before the `return results;` statement:

```
Task[] taskList = { t1, t2, t3 };
Task.WaitAll(taskList);
```

My question is this. Why do we use `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` when we also have to manually call Wait method for every child Task?

**Edit:**

While I was writing this question, I've changed code a little bit and now AttachedToParent works well. The only difference is that I've used `parentTask.Start();` instead of the `Task.Run();`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<int[]> parentTask = new Task<int[]>(()=> 
        {
            int[] results = new int[3];

            Task t1 = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); results[0] = 0; }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            Task t2 = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); results[1] = 1; }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            Task t3 = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); results[2] = 2; }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            t3.Start();

            //Task[] taskList = { t1, t2, t3 };
            //Task.WaitAll(taskList);

            return results;
        });

        parentTask.Start();

        Task finalTask = parentTask.ContinueWith(parent =>
        {
            foreach (int result in parent.Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        });

        finalTask.Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I still don't understand why there is a problem with the first example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Look at this blog post: [*Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

The first example:

```
Task.Run(someAction);
```

is simplified equivalent of method:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction,
         CancellationToken.None,
         TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
         TaskScheduler.Default);
```

I made little research, using reflector, here is a source of method `Task.Run`

```
public static Task Run(Func<Task> function, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      if (function == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
      cancellationToken.ThrowIfSourceDisposed();
      if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        return Task.FromCancellation(cancellationToken);
      else
        return (Task) new UnwrapPromise<VoidTaskResult>(
            (Task) Task<Task>.Factory.StartNew(function,
                                  cancellationToken, 
                                  TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
                                  TaskScheduler.Default),
            true);
    }
```

The important parameter of method `Task.Factory.StartNew` is `TaskCreationOptions creationOptions`. In method `Task.Factory.StartNew` that parameter equals `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach`. It mean that

> an InvalidOperationException will be thrown if an attempt is made to
>   attach a child task to the created task

You need to change to `TaskCreationOptions.None` to achieve right behavior of code.

Method `Task.Run` **does not provide ability to change TaskCreationOptions parameter.**

Comment: *DenyChildAttach* really seems to be the problem. When I create parent task like this: `TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskContinuationOptions.None); 
Task<int[]> parentTask = tf.StartNew(() => {....});` I get the same problem and when I use *TaskCreationOptions.None* it works fine.